# How to reference the redirected window created after successful login/authorization?

Tags: javascript, redirect, reference, oauth-2.0, greasemonkey

I am trying to de-bug a javascript code that is run as a GreaseMonkey userscript on www.site1.com. This userscript:

- generates a button on www.site1.com that then ...
- initiates OAuth2 implicit grant authorization/login to www.site2.com, and then...
- **extracts token information from the redirected window that appears following successful authentication/login**. <-- the problem!!

This last step is the one that is giving me problems, which I think can be summarized as follows:  I don't know how to make my userscript reference the "redirect window" that is created by www.site2.com upon successful login/authentication.

The userscript can easily reference the login window itself, e.g. through "authWin" if the login window is generated as below:

```
var authWin = open.window("https://api.site2.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=0000&redirect_uri=http://www.site2.com/newsfeed&response_type=token&scope=all
```

But as soon as I successfully log in, that login "child" window disappears and is replaced by the "redirect" window.  **Since that window was NOT generated directly by my userscript via open.window(), how can I reference that "redirected window" so that I can extract the token information from its url?**  I am certain that I must be missing something really fundamental, given that this kind of authentication process is performed on many websites out there. A search for the words "window, handler, reference" on this site did not produce any answers that looked relevant to my posed question here ([Angular2 - Redirect to calling url after successful login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020703/angular2-redirect-to-calling-url-after-successful-login) came closest, but not quite the same problem).  *I have spend 2+ solid months trying to write this code; any help would be greatly appreciated.*

Relevant pieces of my GreaseMonkey code are included below:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @include     https://www.site1.com/*
// other metadata as needed
// ==/UserScript==

var redirectUrl = "https://www.site2.com"
var urlAuth       = "https://api.site2.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=0000&redirect_uri=http://www.site2.com/newsfeed&response_type=token&scope=all
var accessToken   = null;

/* MAKE BUTTON on www.site1.com */
var input = document.createElement("input"); 
input.type = "button"; 
input.value="Update bibtex"; 
input.onclick = getBib; 
input.setAttribute("style", "font-size:18px; position:absolute; bottom:10px; left:10px;");
document.body.appendChild(input);

/* Below is what happens when button is pushed */
function getBib() {    
    var win =  window.open(urlAuth, "GM to API Auth Window", 
                           "resizeable, scrollbars, status", 
                           "toolbar, dependent, width=660, height=480");   
     var pollTimer   = window.setInterval(function() { 
       try { 
/* The code will start monitoring the URL once every 100 microseconds (see below)
to see if the URL contains the words "access_token=". */
         if (window.location.href.indexOf("access_token=") != -1) {
/* If the current URL contains those words, then the user has logged in successfully. */
            window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
/* stop the monitoring. */
            var url = window.location.href; 
/* store the current url (which contains important information provided from the API), and get the 
 token and other relevant info: */
            acToken   = gup(url, 'access_token');
    }
  } catch(e) { 
    } 
}, 100); 
} 

function gup(url, param) { 
  var apiInfo = url.split('#')[1];
/* Define the search by attaching an equal sign to the desired parameter */
  var searchStr = param + "=";
/* Look for the requested parameter */
  var pos = apiInfo.indexOf(searchStr); 
  var parVal = null;
  if (pos != -1) { 
/* clip everything to the right of an including the equal sign. If pos=-1, then the param does not appear in URL so return null */
       apiInfo = apiInfo.substring(pos + searchStr.length);
/* Now split out by the apersand and select the section of characters to the right of the first apersand */
       parVal = apiInfo.split("&")[0];
  }
  return parVal;
}
```

Comment: Assuming the userscript runs on all three URLs, I would spoof `unsafeWindow.open` in userscript instance that runs in auth window with a wrapper function that adds `&my_script_name_token=123` parameter to the redirect window's URL so that the userscript instance that runs there would read that parameter and store the extracted token via GM_setValue('token123', token), while the original userscript instance would poll GM_getValue periodically for that value.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm!  I am very new at Javascript, and unfortunately I don't follow your suggestion, but it gives me much-needed hope that there is a solution!   Would you mind giving me a little more hand-holding and walking me through the steps to implement your suggestions?  (I have no idea how to spoof a window, nor how to  inject the `&my_script_name_token=123` to the redirect window's URL, unless you mean that I should make `&my_script_name_token=123` as part of the `redirect_uri` parameter that gets fed to `open.window` as part of the URL that brings up the login window? )

Comment: @wOxxOm, I edited my question to include the code I've been working with.  Perhaps you could tell/show me where/how to incorporate the unsafeWindow.open spoofing, the wrapper function that adds my_script_name_token=123 and the periodic polling of the GM_getValue to obtain the token? (I get a feeling that I might be 95% of the way there, as I do periodic polling of the URL name to find the occurrence of "access_token=", which would indicate a successful login and time to extract the token from the hash fragment.  But the polling does not work because my code can't "see" the redirected window).