# Angular 6 - RouterStateSnapshot state.url returns '/dashboard' when initializing the app'

Tags: angular, routes

I have an app where the routes look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
            { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
            {
                path: 'patients',
                loadChildren: 'app/patients/patients.module#PatientsModule'
            },
            { path: 'calendar', component: CalendarComponent },
            { path: 'messages', component: MessagesComponent }
        ]
    },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

There is a login page where the user is landed first and following an authGuard that protects the dashboard pages. The authGuard takes care that the user will not be navigated to the dashboard pages unless he/she signs in.

The authGuard looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authService: AuthService) { }

    canActivate(route, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        // if the user has logged in return true
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) return true;

        // otherwise redirect user to login page and return false
       this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});

        console.log(state.url); // returns '/dashboard'
        return false;
    }
}
```

I give the possibility to the user to type a desired route in case it is known to navigate directly to the desired page in the form of returnUrl="desiredRoute"

Once the user has logged in in the Dashboard if he/she removes the route I give the possibility to be navigated back to the dashboard so an item in a sidebar is always selected.

The unexpected behavior probably arises from this.

when I start the server and open the browser the app starts with route: `http://localhost:4200/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard` while I would like to start with `http://localhost:4200/login`.

Is there a way to configure my routes so the app starts with `http://localhost:4200/login` and keep the behaviors I described above?

Edit: my issue is exactly identical with this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2-5-registration-login-example?file=app%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts) with a small difference. The difference is that in the example, page is redirected to '' thus the landing page is `login?returnUrl=%2F`. I don't know but is this an expected behavior or not?

Comment: You can add this entry inside the routes array.{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/login' }

Comment: where exactly to place that? Under login path?

Comment: This answer may useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59008239/7059557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround that I finally implemented that keeps almost all previous applied behaviors except for one feature is the following:

Once logged in I removed the redirection to dashboard, therefore now  RouterStateSnapshot state.url returns '/' when initializing the app':

app.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
            { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
            {
                path: 'patients',
                loadChildren: 'app/patients/patients.module#PatientsModule'
            },
            { path: 'calendar', component: CalendarComponent },
            { path: 'messages', component: MessagesComponent }
        ]
    },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

Then in the Guard I did the following to make it possible to redirect to "/login" in the first place:

```
canActivate(route, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        // if the user has logged in return true
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) return true;

        // if state.url === '/' navigate to '/login', 
        // otherwise redirect user to login page and include queryParams
        state.url === '/' ? this.router.navigate(['/login']) :
            this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you want to take to login Page. Here is the updated Router config

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
            { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
            {
                path: 'patients',
                loadChildren: 'app/patients/patients.module#PatientsModule'
            },
            { path: 'calendar', component: CalendarComponent },
            { path: 'messages', component: MessagesComponent }
        ]
    },
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/login' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
```

The authGuard looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authService: AuthService) { }

    canActivate(route, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        // if the user has logged in return true
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) return true;

        // otherwise redirect user to login page and return false
       this.router.navigate(['/login']);

        // console.log(state.url); // returns '/dashboard'
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still landing on 'http://localhost:4200/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard` because state.url is equal to ''/dashboard" for some reason

Comment: Updated the AuthGuard Code.

Comment: If I remove `{ queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }}` from AuthGuard I will land on localhost:4200/login but will not be able to redirect user to the previous url he/she typed. As I mentioned in the description I want to maintain the behaviours I implemented so far.

Comment: Maintain the URL state in service. If service value exist, redirect to respective view. else redirect to login.