# why does the page not redirect to userprofile, but instead home page?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, jwt

This is the link to the application.
[App](https://young-peak-56850.herokuapp.com/)

PROBLEM: when i try going to the user profile page, it nicely redirects to the login page, and then goes back to the home page, which is not its intented route.

THOUGHT: figured out the cause( atleast i think) is in the login function, beacuse the its redirected to home everytime a user loggs in. And so tried to tweak around but in vain.

this is the user service

```
export class UserService() {
  private addrr = '/api';
  return: string = '';
  token: string;

  constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Get the query params
    this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe(params => this.return = params['return'] || '/home');
  }

  // get("/api/users/userReg")
  getUser(): Promise<void | User[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.addrr + '/users/userReg')
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as User[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }


  // post("/api/users/register")
  createUser(newUser: User): Promise<void | User> {
    return this.http.post(this.addrr + '/users/register', newUser)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as User)
      .then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/users/login']);
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  //login
  login(authCridentials: User): Promise<void | User> {

    return this.http.post(this.addrr + '/users/authenticate', authCridentials)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as User)
      .then((respond) => {
        this.setToken(respond['token']);
        // this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        this.router.navigate([this.return]);
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  logout() {
    this.token = null;
    localStorage.clear();
  }

  setToken(token) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  }

  deleteToke() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }

  getUserPayLoad() {
    var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      var UserPayLoad = atob(token.split('.')[1]);
      return JSON.parse(UserPayLoad)
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    var UserPayLoad = this.getUserPayLoad();
    if (UserPayLoad) {
      return UserPayLoad.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}




this is app routung 
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.guard';
import { UserProfileComponent } from './user-profile/user-profile.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: './users/users.module#UsersModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'userprofile',
    component: UserProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  providers: [AuthGuard],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }


this is authguard

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanLoad } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from '../shared/user.service';
import { Router, Route } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanLoad {


  constructor(public userService: UserService, private router: Router) { }

  canLoad(route: Route): boolean {

    if (this.userService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.router.navigate(['/admin/list']);
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/users/login']);
    return false;
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.userService.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/users/login']);
  }

}


this is link in navbar

routerLink="/userprofile"
```

Comment: can you share stackblitz so that we can edit there?

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020703/angular2-redirect-to-calling-url-after-successful-login

Comment: @programoholic ive ttried the solution but its not working

Comment: can share your code demo either through plunkr or stackblitz?