# How to verify the token in the param is correct when reseting password in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, token

I am trying to build password reset feature in my application.The steps will be as follows:

1. Enter Email and click 'Send reset link to email'
2. In his email, he will get a link something like : '**www.domainname.com/api/password-reset?token-idxxxxxxxxx**'
3. When clicked the link he will be redirected to a password reset page to enter his new credentials.

My question is how to verify the token in the param is correct or not. For example if someone copy paste the URL and change the token a bit like : **www.domainname.com/api/password-reset?token-id-newyyyyyy**, then he shouldn't be redirected to reset page. How do I prevent this. 
My assumption is: When I am redirected to the reset page then I hit another API, which will send me the Token value and I will compare this token value with the params token and if not match I will redirect to another page. But I am sure this is not the most correct way. Do I have to do something from the backend. How do I prevent the reset page from being shown in case if wrong token is entered in the URL params ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `www.domainname.com/api/password-reset?token-idxxxxxxxxx` so when the user will open this link from their email you first call a token verify api in the backend. If the token is verified send success status and if not send unauthorized. Based on this response you can redirect user to view the enter password page or show an error.

To help you more with the flow :

1. User clicks this link `www.domainname.com/api/password-reset?token-idxxxxxxxxx`
2. Backend api is called in this component say verify user.
3. Based on that api response you will load reset password component

service will be like :

```
verifyUser(data): Observable < any > {
  return this.http.post(environment.serverUrl + 'verifyUser', data).pipe(
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => throwError(error))
  )
}
```

and subscribe like :

```
this.empService.verifyUser(data).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log("Response", res);
      if (res.message == "success") {

        this.router.navigateByUrl('/resetPassword');
        } else {
        // Some error Message
        }
      }
    },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log("error")
      })
```

Comment: Feel free to ask if not clear. I hope above flow helps you with the logic!

Comment: Hey Thanx. I was also thinking about this scenario only. Glad to get an answer. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Since you are sending password reset link to user's registered email, you do not need to append token in the reset link. 
Also sharing token is not recommend:

1. Every token has its lifecycle period throughout which it remains valid. For example 20 minutes or 1 hour.
2. So if any other user has access to this token then he/she can use it to get access to private data.

In your case you should redirect user to your regular password reset link (**www.domainname.com/api/password-reset**).
After clicking on the link user will be redirected to password reset page of your application, here are two scenarios:

1. If user has already logged in into the application, in that case you can directly show password reset page.
2. If user has not already logged in into the application, in that case first you can redirect to login page then after successful login with current password you can show password reset page.

Please refer below answer on redirecting to calling link after successful login:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40021645/9444169

Comment: How can user login if he forgot the password for which he is trying to reset it again. I tried to see how https://www.hackerrank.com/ is doing it. I saw that they are also sending a token in the URL to redirect to the reset page. If i make changes to the token than I am not shown the reset password page

Comment: "Forgot Password" and "Reset Password" are two different things altogether. In case for forgot password, you don't have to pass token anywhere instead you should follow regular "Send OTP" via SMS or email. Also almost in all the websites these tokens are getting stored into "LocalStorage" at client side and then they passed as headers into every request.