# Angular8 - Redirecting page after successful post request

Tags: angular, cookies

I am working on an angular application which needs to redirect after a successful post request.
Both of these work fine, however there are cookies being set from the first call which get lost after the redirect.
Is there any way of keeping those even after redirect?
Here is my code:

```
this.httpService.loginHttp(loginRequest).subscribe(response => {
        let redirectUrl = response.url;
        window.location.replace(redirectUrl);
}
```

Post request Looks like this:

```
loginHttp(req: any): Observable<any>{
let url = this.baseURL;
let header = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this.http.post<any>(url, req, {
  headers: header
  })
}
```

The request Header from the first post call is like this:

```
* access-control-allow-credentials: true
* access-control-allow-headers: content-type, authorization, token
* access-control-allow-methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
* access-control-allow-origin: *
* access-control-expose-headers: token
* Set-Cookie: IDNum=1000; Path=/; SameSite=none; Secure
* Set-Cookie: CROSSDetails=XPP; Path=/; SameSite=none; Secure
```

The cookies IDNum=1000, CROSSDetails=XPP  get lost after the redirection.

**Please Note**: Domain for both the first page and redirection page are the same. So I don't think that is a problem.

Comment: What is your backend language?

Comment: Backend is Java

Comment: you can use local storage to save this value

Comment: @ShwetaSingh, Please Check this Link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020703/angular2-redirect-to-calling-url-after-successful-login

Comment: @AsmaaRashad, I could  try that but I am unable to get those 'Set-Cookie' to my angular after the post request. Anything you can help me find how to save those values in angular?

Comment: @SunnyVakil, The link above has issues around navigating, my issues are around the cookies. The cookies get lost after navigating.