# Angular Inherit component

Tags: angular

How would you go about this?

I created a login component `<app-customer-login>`, which redirects you to your account page once you are successfully logged in.

So far so good.

I also have a checkout flow, which checks if you are logged in or not. If not, I like to show the same login component. So the user can immediately login. If I implement `<app-customer-login>` in the checkout flow, then the user will be redirected to the account page once successfully logged in.

How can I redirect the user to a different page if the user logs in from a different page (checkout page).

Can I somehow determine which page implements the `<app-customer-login>`?

I understand the use of guards. The `"issue"` is that I use a wizard with steps for the checkout flow.

1. show the cart
2. Check if the user is logged in or not. If not not I like to use `<app-customer-login>` component, but then it should not redirect the user to the account page, but back to the wizard.
3. Address
4. Payment

Comment: i am not sure that i am correct or not but as i understand your problem you need to decide either need to transfer user to login & if user already logged in then just transfer to account so for that purpose angular provides guard inbuild which is helpful to you https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/router-guards/

Comment: let me know if i am not correctly understand your problem

Comment: I tried to edit the original question, to be more explicit

Comment: ok Means if user is not logged in then you redirect user to login page and when again user come from login then you need to move to wizard not to account i am right? for same thing you can save information like ComeToLoginFrom Value should be "Origin" Or "Wizard". once successfully login check the value of this cookie value if it is Wizard then need to selected third wizrd as selected.

Comment: Refer below already asked question may be useful to you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020703/angular2-redirect-to-calling-url-after-successful-login

Answer (score 1):

I solved it now like this:

```
      if(this.router.url.indexOf('/login')) {
        this.customerAccountService.redirectToAccount();
      } else {
        this.customerAccountService.redirectToWizard();
      }
```

Maybe there is a nicer option as well ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally add an if statment on your login component to check where the user came from to redirect them to the cart or wherever you want to send them.

Comment: ok, but how can I know where the user came from?

or which component implemented <app-customer-login> ?