# How to properly look into history of router

Tags: angular, router

I have this situation :

- An user click a link, like from skype or something.
- The url the user want to acces require the user to be logged.
- After the login, the user should be redirected to that link he clicked instead of the root of the app.

So far, that's my login component:

```
login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
        .takeWhile(() => this.isAlive)
            .subscribe(result => {
                if (result) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                } else {
                    this.error = 'Error.';
                    this.loading = false;
                }
            },
            err => {
                this.translation[err.description] ? this.error = this.translation[err.description] : this.error = this.error = err.description;
                this.loading = false;
            })
    }
```

I have no idea on how to do it, but I think I should look at routerHistory in the true statement `if(result)`.

How to properly do this?

**Edit and solution**

I finally solved this problem.

`CanActivate`

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
       console.log(state.url);
    }
```

`state.url` contains the previous url, so I just putted it into a Subject and subscribed where I needed it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Redirect After Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36160118/angular2-redirect-after-login)

Comment: Not really sadly, is an old answer